# Landscape Autopilot Openstack stuck at checklist "One on the public net"

Tags: networking, juju, maas, openstack, landscape

I am trying to install Autopilot Openstack with Landscape. I have 8 physical servers, 1 for MAAS, 1 for JUJU gui, 1 for Landscape, 5 for openstacks. Each server has two physical NICs (public and private). The two different networks are divided by two VLAN but in the same switch.

Currently, I am at the step where landscape checks lists that are required.
But, **One on the public net** is still grayed-out on the Checklist.

I am wondering

- How I can get passed the checklist
- How Landscape and MAAS check a single node has at least one public net
- Did I made a mistake on Open vSwitch where a public network is set up?

Landscape dashboard:

[image: Landscape dashboard]

Open vSwitch:

[image: [Open vSwitch]

Answer (score 1):

I looked over your excellent question, and my only suggestion is that I would need to see the MAAS configuration to verify things, but this *should* be correct, and I don't see any immediate problems in your setup.  It could be a newer version of MAAS changed APIs a bit, and the Autopilot tool no longer correctly talks to it (i.e., BUG).

However, I'm posting this here so you know the Autopilot tool is no longer being developed.

Please see the following for the official word on the Openstack "Autopilot" offering in the Landscape tool:

https://insights.ubuntu.com/2014/11/06/putting-your-openstack-on-autopilot/

Specifically, Here is the text from Canonical:

> Thanks for your interest in Ubuntu OpenStack. Canonical has sunsetted
>   OpenStack Autopilot and replaced it with [conjure-up](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/try-openstack). We welcome you to
>   visit our [OpenStack product page](https://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/openstack) to find an Ubuntu OpenStack solution
>   that meets your needs.